# How can I whitelist MAC addresses in my Hub3.0 Virgin Media router?

Tags: wireless-networking

I’d like to create a white list of MAC addresses at home so that only those devices have WIFI.

I'm confused by the router interface, I said offers two different ways to manage access control:

I know how to block devices with Mac filtering, but what I want to do is to create a white list, so that no other devices can join in.

So I headed to the Advanced Settings > Wireless > Security (see first pic below) and set “Wireless Mac filtering” to “allow”, my understanding is that if I don't add any Mac addresses here, then no device will be able to join the network. However this isn't the case I can use the 2.4 and 5GHz with my smartphone all the same, while not added to the list.

I wonder what I am doing wrong.

I couldn't find a proper guide for this router.

Any help much appreciated.

Router Virgin Media Hub 3.0 VMGD505 (manufactured by Arris)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Doesn't the WPA password already serve this purpose? (As in, don't want a device to have Wi-Fi -- don't give it the Wi-Fi password?)

Comment: I'm not quite sure where you're struggling. Type device name, MAC address 'both 2.4 & 5' then hit Add. Switch off WPA, though, only use WPA2 these days. Note that MAC address filtering isn't particularly secure, it can be spoofed by someone determined enough, though they'd still have to figure out the password. Don't make that too easy.

Comment: my understanding is that if I don't add any Mac addresses here, then no device will be able to join the network. However this isn't the case, I can use the 2.4 and 5GHz with my smartphone all the same, while not added to the list.

Comment: Still not clear… if it's already connected, it will still be allowed. Bear in mind we cannot see over your shoulder; you have to tell us exactly what you did & what the results were. 'my smartphone' isn't a valid description of the data as presented.